# Websphere MQ series - MQGMO_WAIT

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm about to refactor a broker application written for websphere MQ. In the existing application, while reading a message from the queue, the following options are being set:

MQConstants.MQGMO_WAIT and

waitInterval = 1000 (milliseconds).

In our application, there is no guarantee that we receive a message every second. We may not receive a message even for hours. I'm not sure why the creators of this application chose to go for waitInterval = 1000 instead of setting the waitInterval to MQWI_UNLIMITED.
At the moment, there is a catch block in the code which does not do anything when MQException.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE occurs.

The creators of this application were really smart people so I do not know why they opted for this approach. I'm new to MQ series, so can anyone please explain the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

Well its just to check the queue every second for a message. You can be more intelligent by using features like async message delivery in a thread of use some of the new features of MQ that does not do lot of polling on the Queue.